# SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: style.scss

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I am trying to setup a vuejs project from scratch. I am getting this error when I import "style.scss" in the component. Here's the component (*Login.vue*) where I import the style.scss

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <h1>This is login page</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Login"
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @import 'style.scss';
</style>
```

Here is my folder structure. *style.scss* is under */src* and the component *Login.vue* is under */src/views*:

[image: vue folder structure]

I even tried changing the import to

```
@import '/style.scss';    //and
@import '../style.scss';
```

Here's my webpack configuration of sass-loader

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'sass-loader'
    ]
}
```

Comment: You want `@import '../styles.scss'`. Note that _"styles"_ is plural

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file name is "styles" not "style".

Try one of those three file path options you listed above. I'm pretty sure either `@import '/styles.scss';`   or `@import '../styles.scss';` should work for you.

Comment: Ohh! my bad. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Happens to everyone!